# function for calculating time difference on foreach item results same data

Tags: php, methods, pdo, foreach

Im making a orderlist. Each order has a datetime column. What i want to do is subtrackt the order datetime from the current time to get the diffrence. I tried following

data is PDO result of objects

```
<?php
$order = new Order();
$elapsedTime = new Order();

foreach ($order->data() as $key=>&$orderItem) {
//get time diffrence                            
$time1 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i")); //now
$time2 = date('H:i', strtotime($orderItem->orderdate));
echo '
<tr id="row' . $orderItem->orderid . '">
<td class="hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs center">' . $orderItem->orderid . '</td>
<td>
' . $elapsedTime->getElapsedTime($time1,$time2) . '
</td>
<td class="center"><B>' . date('d/m H:i', strtotime($orderItem->orderdate)) . '</B></td>
</tr>
';
    }
?>
```

and method

```
    public function getElapsedTime($time1, $time2) {
    $diff = $time1 - $time2;

    if($diff){
    return 'Diff: '.date('H:i', $diff);
    }else{
    return 'No Diff.';
    //date('Y-m-d H:i',$diff);
    }
    return false;
}
```

but for some reason i get all exact same results.. but when i just echo the $orderItem->orderdate all dates differ

Comment: `$time` is an integer, `$time2` is a string. You can't subtract them and get a meaningful result.

Comment: oh wow... did not even notice that...  im gonna try new things with your responses and let yall know thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your function code with:

```
$start_date = new DateTime($time1);
$end_date = new DateTime($time2);
$interval = $start_date->diff($end_date);
return $interval->format('%a');
```

And as @Barmar said, $time2 is a string so the 7th line in your code should be changed from:

```
$time2 = date('H:i', strtotime($orderItem->orderdate));
```

to:

```
$time2 = strtotime($orderItem->orderdate);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time1 = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i")); //now
$time2 = date('H:i', strtotime($orderItem->orderdate));
```

`$time1` is a timestamp (int), whereas `$time2` is a string. So when calculating `$diff` later, you substract a string from an integer, which gives you unexpected results.

Better keep both timestamps as integer, so that you can substract them from each other later:

```
$time1 = time(); // No need for date/strtotime here
$time2 = strtotime($orderItem->orderdate); // Keep the timestamp as int
```